# Executing a JS function on page load, based on user input from previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

OUTLINE:
I have a products page with a working jQuery filtering system based on products class names. I have provided a basic example of my code below:

```js
// PRODUCTS PAGE FUNCTIONS
function filterAll() {
  $('.download').show("slow");
  $('.ourprod').show("slow");
  $('.accessories').show("slow");
  $('.club').show("slow");
}

function filterClubs() {
  $('.download').hide("slow");
  $('.ourprod').hide("slow");
  $('.accessories').hide("slow");
  $('.club').show("slow");
}

function filterProds() {
  $('.download').hide("slow");
  $('.club').hide("slow");
  $('.accessories').hide("slow");
  $('.ourprod').show("slow");
}

function filterAccess() {
  $('.download').hide("slow");
  $('.club').hide("slow");
  $('.ourprod').hide("slow");
  $('.accessories').show("slow");
}

function filterVideos() {
  $('.accessories').hide("slow");
  $('.club').hide("slow");
  $('.ourprod').hide("slow");
  $('.download').show("slow");
}

//HOMEPAGE FUNCTION
function loadProductsPage() {
  window.location = 'products.php';
}

// PRODUCTS PAGE EVENTS
$('#filterall').click(function() {
  filterAll();
});
$('#filterclubs').click(function() {
  filterClubs();
});
$('#filterprods').click(function() {
  filterProds();
});
$('#filteraccessories').click(function() {
  filterAccess();
});
$('#filtervideos').click(function() {
  filterVideos();
});
```

```css
.box {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px float: left;
}
.filter a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="shop-filter">
  <section class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="filter nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a id="filterall">All</a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="filterclubs">Clubs</a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="filterprods">Our Products</a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="filteraccessories">Accessories</a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="filtervideos">Videos</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</nav>

<div class="box club">
  <h4>CLUB</h4> 
  <span> - $89.99</span>
</div>
<div class="box ourprod">
  <h4>PRODUCT</h4>
  <span> - $39.99</span>
</div>
<div class="box download">
  <h4>Download</h4>
  <span> - $9.95</span>
</div>
<div class="box accessories">
  <h4>Accessories</h4>
  <span> - $XX.XX</span>
</div>
```

PROBLEM: 
On the homepage I have links that I would like to direct to the products page BUT with the corresponding filter applied after the page loads. Here is the homepage HTML, which is linked to the above scripts:

```html
<a id="loadclubs" href="javascript:void(0)">
  <h1>Training Clubs</h1>
</a>
<a id="loadvideos" href="javascript:void(0)">
  <h1>Training Videos</h1>
</a>
<a id="loadaccessories" href="javascript:void(0)">
  <h1>Accessories</h1>
</a>
```

I am new to jQuery/Javascript so any other advice to clean up my scripts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As you are linking to the next page without posting data, you will need to use some sort of method to store information and retrieve it on the next page. This will then need to be read by the javascript to modify the DOM. There are some ways to do this:

1. request parameters: `<a href=newpage.html?from=accessories>`, then in the next page, `var req = get('from'); // == accesories` (where req() is a function that gets request variables), then when the page loads, modify the DOM by either calling the appropriate function or by simply hiding items as required.

eg.

first page: `<a id="loadclubs" href="item?id=123&filter=accessories">Training Clubs</h1></a>`

second page:

```
<script>
    var filter = .....; // get the filter param

    if (filter == "accessories") { filterAccess(); }
       OR
    if (filter == "accessories") {
        $('.download').css("display", "none");
        $('.club').css("display", "none");
        $('.ourprod').css("display", "none");
        $('.accessories').css("display", "initial");
    }
</script>
```

2. localstorage: similar to the above, but when a link is clicked, store values into localstorage, then retreieve it in the next page and once again call the display functions/hide items.
3. Mix of request parameters and controller methods - depending on the request parameters, initially style the links with display properties.